# Scraping the table row by row? Python Webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

If you go to this link: https://www.halton.ca/For-Residents/Food-Safety/Dinewise/Search-Directory-of-Food-Premises-Dinewise and click on a restaurant and see this page.

[image]

I want to scrape all the information in this table.

At first I tried using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Form1"]/table[1]').text)
```

Which did get my information for parts of the table. However, since under 'Satisfactory', 'Corrected at time of inspection', and 'Not Applicable' are images. This method wouldn't allow me to get the text of it. Therefore I was considering that I could get the source link and determine whether it is yes or no.

My question is how do I scrape this table row by row? This is my attempt at it and I was not able to scrape the 'Description' portion

```
 # Get Areas of Assessment, Description then Satisfactory
        table =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Form1"]/table[1]/tbody')
        rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")  # get all of the rows in the table
        
        content = []
        
        for row in range(1, len(rows)+1):
            # Get the columns (all the column 2)
            
            #areas of assessment
            a = rows[row].find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Form1"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[1]/b'%row).text
            content.append(a)
            print(content)
            print(a)
            #description
            b =rows[row].find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Form1"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/br').text
            print(b)
            #satisfactory
#             test =rows[row].find_element_by_id('chkFoodProtectedFromContamination_Satisfactory').get_attribute("src")
            print(test)
```

Comment: for description - why did not use tr[%s] on the xpath ? . try ('//*[@id="Form1"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[2]'%row).text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do the following to retrieve the src of an image.

```
c = rows[row].find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Form1"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[3]/img').getAttribute("src")
print(c)
```